# Referencing class function variables in php

Tags: php, scope

I've been looking over the PHP variable scope reference page and I can't seem to find a clear answer. I'm working with this basic model where I want to call a class function and have all of its variables accessible outside the class. I want to avoid using the global declaration as well and do this in the most efficient way possible.

```
class my_class() {
    function my_class_function() {
        $my_class_function_variable = 'juice';
            return $my_class_function_variable;
    }
}
$class_instance = new my_class();

function display_juice() {
    $class_instance::my_class_function();
    $my_class_function_variable;
}
```

Is there a quick answer in what I'm missing? I'm not getting any output or errors.

**EDIT**

I'm getting a syntax error when I declare the following within the class but not within the function.

```
public $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Variable scope, read all about it.... if you want a class variable, define it as a public class property

Comment: There is so much wrong: static call, no return, not a class member, instance not passed to function .. wow ..

Comment: Your question is NOT complete and clear.. P.S. and at your example code you don't do any action .. 1 class (with 1 function) , second function and one $call_instance ...
I don't have idea what you want to happen...

Comment: By the way declaration of class's don't have ().. its not a function

Comment: @Svetlio Thanks for that last note. I want to echo the variable from the class function. This is just an example. I really have lots of variables defined in a class function and I want to call them from outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all setted variables in class if they are public.
And you can access any of its function if its again public...
Here is example . I have default value 'mydefault'.
I use it, then I change it and again I use it..

```
class my_class {
    public $variable = "mydefault";

    public function change_variable($value) {
        $this->variable = $value;
    }
}

function display_juice() {
    $class = new my_class;
    echo $class->variable; // echo default value - 'mydefault'
    $class->change_variable('newvalue');    
    echo $class->variable; // echo default value - 'newvalue'
}

display_juice();
```

Edit..

```
class my_class {
    public $variable;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->variable = wp_get_current_user();
    }
}
```

Comment: see my edit, I'm getting an error when I declare a public variable as a global WP function.

Comment: You can't set functions for default values.
add 1 constructer function to set it.. like my edit..

Comment: can you put conditionals in the __construct?

Comment: __construct is a function which is before all others.. so why not ? I had mistake with construct name :) sorry for that

Comment: It just seems odd, for example, if you're familiar with WP functions, there is one called get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key'); If I declare that in the __construct function, the value has to change for each $post->ID, so I'm not sure why I'm setting the variable when I call the class. It should be that when I call the function, ie display_juice, that that new variable is called, not on initializaztion.

Comment: Ah, you know what? I just didn't define them in __construct. I'm not really sure why you chose to set the variable in __construct when you can just define it in display_juice

Comment: To not use the constructor you can make inside the class one function set_variable($value)
and from outsite to write $class->set_variable(wp_get_current_user());
And this way your class wont have to use that wp function ..
There are many ways to do what you want, its your task to decide which is the best one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You currently don't return anything, you would have to do something like this:

```
class my_class() {
    function my_class_function() {
        $my_class_function_variable = 'juice';
        return $my_class_function_variable;
    }
}

function display_juice() {
    $class_instance = new my_class(); //Needs to be inside the function
    $my_class_function_variable = $class_instance->my_class_function();
    echo $my_class_function_variable;
}
display_juice();
```

If you want to use a static function or variable you could do this, which eliminates the need for having to create an instance of my_class:

```
class my_class() {
    static function my_class_function() {
        return 'juice';
    }
}

function display_juice() {
    $my_class_function_variable = my_class::my_class_function();
    echo $my_class_function_variable;
}
display_juice();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make my_class_function() static, the you can call it with my_class::my_class_function()

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Also as suggested bellow, you need to return 'juice'.

```
return 'juice';
```

Answer (score -3):

I would make the variable you're trying to access a public member

```
class my_class {
   public $my_class_function_variable = 'juice';
   public function my_class_function() {

   }
}
$class_instance = new my_class();

function display_juice() {
     echo my_class->$my_class_function_variable;
}

display_juice();
```